# Getting next item in an array of values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to get every output out of a json file.  So far I have:

```
$json_feed = file_get_contents($indy_feed_url);
$json_items = json_decode($json_feed, TRUE);

$individual = $json_items['indy'][0];
```

and then echo things out.

This works fine for item 0.  However, I want to do all items.

The number of items in the json file varies from time to time so I cannot just enter like 10 here because sometimes there might be 20 or 5 etc.

How can I do this in a loop so that it counts the number of items and loops that many times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement:

```
foreach($json_items['indy'] as $item) {
    // do whatever you want with $item
}
```